# Calculate distance in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate the distance between sequential points and partitioned by the ID number in BigQuery.

Here's what my table looks like:

```
OBJECTID    ID DateAndTime           Lat         Long
 1           1  2002-11-26T12:00:00  38.82551095 -109.9709871
 2           1  2002-11-29T13:00:00  38.541137   -109.677575
 3           2  2002-11-03T10:00:00  38.550676   -109.901774
 4           2  2002-11-04T10:00:00  38.53689    -109.683531
 5           2  2002-11-05T10:00:00  38.45689    -109.683531
```

Based on the above table, I'd want the query to calculate the distance between `ObjectID` 1 & 2, and then the distance between `ObjectID` 3 & 4 and then 4 & 5

Here's a query I've ***started*** for ordering by `DateAndTime` and finding the time difference. In this query I was trying to find time differences over 12hours. Is it similar logic to this? How can I calculate distances between sequenced points in BigQuery?

```
SELECT *,
DATETIME_DIFF( prev_DateAndTime, DateAndTime, hour) as diff_hours
FROM 
(SELECT points.ID, points.DateAndTime,
LAG(DateAndTime) OVER (PARTITION BY points.ID ORDER BY points.DateAndTime) as prev_DateAndTime
FROM `table1` AS table1 INNER JOIN 
`table2` AS points ON table1.ID = points.ID
WHERE
(points.DateAndTime BETWEEN table1.BeginDate AND COALESCE (table1.EndDate, CURRENT_DATE() + 1))
And points.DateAndTime between '2020-12-01T00:00:00' and CURRENT_DATE() 
) d
WHERE 
DATETIME_DIFF(prev_DateAndTime, DateAndTime, hour) > 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 objectid, 1 id, timestamp '2002-11-26T12:00:00' DateAndTime, 38.82551095 lat,  -109.9709871 long union all
  select 2, 1, '2002-11-29T13:00:00', 38.541137,  -109.677575 union all
  select 3, 2, '2002-11-03T10:00:00', 38.550676,  -109.901774 union all
  select 4, 2, '2002-11-04T10:00:00', 38.53689,  -109.683531 union all
  select 5, 2, '2002-11-05T10:00:00', 38.45689,  -109.683531 
)
select *, 
  objectid as objectid_start, 
  lead(objectid) over next as objectid_next,
  round(st_distance(st_geogpoint(long, lat), lead(st_geogpoint(long, lat)) over next), 2) as distance
from `project.dataset.table`
window next as (partition by id order by DateAndTime)
-- order by id, DateAndTime
```

with output

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks. Where in this query statement would I add a parameter for "WHERE distance > 500"? I tried adding it in but I get an error that distance is an unknown field name.

Comment: you can wrap whole query with outer one - `select * from ( . . . ) where distance > 500`